# Is it possible to combine Flagbearer and Inspire Courage using Mage Hand?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bard

I want to do the following thing (as a bard):

1. Bardic performance (standard action) (-> Inspire Courage +1)
2. Hold [bardic performance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard) (swift action) + casting [mage hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-hand)
   (standard action) (grab the flag ([flagbearer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/flagbearer-local)) with the mage
   hand)
3. Hold bardic performance (swift) + hold [concentration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/66988/how-does-maintaining-a-concentration-spell-work) for mage
   hand (standard) + move

Is this even possible and would get my allies +2 on Attack, Damage and Saving throughs?

Comment: Side note: Maintaining Bardic Performance is a free action, not a swift action.

Comment: I see no need for mage hand in this. Bardic performance requires no hands by default.

Comment: But I could have a shield and a weapon or cast a spell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [your Flagbearer link](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/flagbearer-local):

> ... You must hold the flag in one hand in order to grant this bonus. ...

Based on that I don't think you can gain the bonus by holding it with your *mage hand*, at least by RAW. You might ask your DM, though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said you should also note

Mage Hand :
"Target one non-magical, unattended object weighing up to 5 lbs."

So you cannot hold a magical banner in it anyway.

Comment: The [flag](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/flagbearer-local)  in question looks like a nonmagical item weighing 3 lbs.

Comment: Doh, looks like you are right, shoul dhave checked it out properly